# Problem with Drag Drop in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am working for the first time on Drag-Drop in MFC and I am stuck very badly.. I see some format being used for intra-list drag-drop and its value is 49391 always. I have no idea where this number is coming from. I have registered only two formats viz CF_HDROP and another private format [ who value does not match with this ].. can someone please help with this ?

And strange enough, when I checked on msdn, it doesn't give any format value this high: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729168%28VS.85%29.aspx .. I am getting this value consistently; inspite of re-builds; restarts etc.. So, I am guessing it must be some kind of standard format.. Any kind of assistance would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MFC generally uses OLE with Drag and Drop under the covers to do it's work, not the clipboard.

[MFC Example](http://www.ucancode.net/faq/MFC-Drag-Drop-Cut-Copy-Paste.htm).

BUT:

[Uniform Data Transfer](http://www.tenouk.com/visualcplusmfc/visualcplusmfc25a.html) One section covers using the clipboard amoung other things.

[Enabling Drag and Drop without OLE](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/dragdrop/article.php/c4059)

Enjoy.